# How to group a List depending on the occurrence?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<Class>` with 15 objects in it.
The data consists of `Strings` and looks something like this:

Profiles
item1
item2
item3
Profiles
item1
item2
Profiles
item
Profiles
item1
item2

What i want to do here is to group the data depending on the Profile occurrences. I want to group new lists containing all profiles with it's items, or maybe use `LINQ` to group them? The result i need looks like this:

```
new List<Class> List1  
    Profiles  
    item1  
    item2  
    item3


new List<Class> List2  
    Profiles  
    item1  
    item2
```

The occurrence of the Profiles and items can vary, anyone with an idea around how to do this?
Hope i was clear.

This is the part of the code where the List is passed into a method and needs to be grouped into different Profiles depending on the occurrence:

```
    private GroupProfiles(List<ProfileItems> allProfiles)  
    {  
           // Do something with allProfiles.
    }
```

Comment: give us real code, this will be easier to help you

Comment: I strongly suspect you want a lookup, but it will be *much* easier to help you with concrete code and data.

Comment: If the profiles are unique you could use a dictionary. Dictionary<IProfile, IList<IItem>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

1. Create a new class with a list-property
2. Create a list of that class
3. Iterate through your list
4. Each time you hit "Profiles" create a new instance of the class and add the following items to the new class, until you hit "Profiles" again.

Hope you understand what I am trying to explain.
Its probably not the best way, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method to split the original list into discrete lists like so:

```
// 'TargetSelector' is a delegate that you use to specify how to get from the class instances
// the string by which you want to group the items.

private static IEnumerable<List<T>> splitBy<T>(string target, List<T> data, Func<T, string> targetSelector)
{
    var group = new List<T>();

    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        if (targetSelector(item) == target)
        {
            if (group.Count > 0)
            {
                yield return group;
                group = new List<T>();
            }
        }

        group.Add(item);
    }

    if (group.Count > 0)
        yield return group;
}
```

Here's a compilable example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string myString)
        {
            MyString = myString;
        }

        public string MyString { get; private set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var strings = new[]
            {
                "Profiles",
                "item1",
                "item2",
                "item3",
                "Profiles",
                "item1",
                "item2",
                "Profiles",
                "item",
                "Profiles",
                "item1",
                "item2"
            };

            // Make a list of "MyClass" items to demonstrate the use of 'splitBy()'.

            var items = strings.Select(str => new MyClass(str)).ToList();

            var profiles = splitBy("Profiles", items, item=>item.MyString).ToList();

            // Now profiles is a list of items separated into profiles. Print them.

            for (int i = 0; i < profiles.Count; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Profile " + i);

                for (int j = 0; j < profiles[i].Count; ++j)
                    Console.WriteLine("  " + profiles[i][j].MyString);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        // 'TargetSelector' is a delegate that you use to specify how to get from the class instances
        // the string by which you want to group the items.

        private static IEnumerable<List<T>> splitBy<T>(string target, List<T> data, Func<T, string> targetSelector)
        {
            var group = new List<T>();

            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                if (targetSelector(item) == target)
                {
                    if (group.Count > 0)
                    {
                        yield return group;
                        group = new List<T>();
                    }
                }

                group.Add(item);
            }

            if (group.Count > 0)
                yield return group;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Profile 0
  Profiles
  item1
  item2
  item3

Profile 1
  Profiles
  item1
  item2

Profile 2
  Profiles
  item

Profile 3
  Profiles
  item1
  item2
```